# Odd exec output in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, exec

I'm trying to determine if a java runtime environment is installed on the computer running my node app. Here's the promise I'm starting to build out to determine if it's installed:

```
FileSystemTools.prototype.checkToSeeIfJavaRuntimeEnvIsAvailable = function (){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec('java -version', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if(error) reject(error)
            if(stderr) reject(stderr)

            resolve(stdout)
        })
    })
}
```

The generator function I'm building out to run this check looks like this so far:

```
co(function *(){
    let jreVersion = yield fst.checkToSeeIfJavaRuntimeEnvIsAvailable()
    console.log(jreVersion)
}).catch(error => {
    throw new Error(error)
})
```

When I run this I get no output at all. However, if I resolve all of the arguments returned from the `exec` command:

```
   FileSystemTools.prototype.checkToSeeIfJavaRuntimeEnvIsAvailable = function (){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec('java -version', (error, stdout, stderr) => {

            // resolving early with everything to see what's going on
            resolve({error, stdout, stderr})


            if(error) reject(error)
            if(stderr) reject(stderr)

            resolve(error, stdout, stderr)
        })
    })
}
```

I'm seeing that my command is firing successful, but it's returning the result in the standard error, not standard output:

```
{
    error: null,
    stdout: '',
    stderr: 'java version "1.8.0_101"\nJava(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)\nJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)\n' 
}
```

I double checked [the docs on the `exec` callback](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) thinking that I got the callback parameters wrong, but they're definitely in the right order:

[image: exec callback parameter order]

This raises two questions for me:

1. Why is my successful output of the command returning in standard error?
2. If it is returning in standard error, why did my if statement to check for standard error and reject if it is truthy not fire?

Comment: @zack6849 I approved the edit. I def agree it's not a java specific question, though I'm assuming that this means there's nothing known to the java community about the version information returning on standard error instead of standard output. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, I just saw @thefourtheye's comment about version returning on standard error so I guess that is a java specific thing ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `java -version` writes its result in standard error only, even though the command is executed successfully. You can confirm that by redirecting the stderr to a file, like this

```
$ sh -c "java -version 2>/tmp/test"
$ cat /tmp/test
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

If there was an error, the `error` parameter in the callback would have been an object, with the error code and the signal.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks re: java version command returning the result on standard error.

Regarding the error, the thing is the `stderr` param _does_ have something in it, though it's not tripping the `if` check. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz You mean the `if(stderr) reject(stderr)`? Yes, the promise will be rejected. I am referring the first program in your question.

Comment: Gotcha. I actually think I figured out the second part of my original question (javascript "truthiness" is an odd thing). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Side note, I have 55 secs before I can actually give you the check ;)